# How can I call getProductQtyIncrements() method from magento_catolog/module-catalog in another module?

Tags: magento2, category, products

I wish the qty valyue could be dynamic (I mean, get another value if product qty had increment) so I create a module and put a helper. Data.php

````
 
  namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;
 
  class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
  {
     public function __construct(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Block\Qtyincrements $qtyIncrements) {
          $this->_qtyIncrements = $qtyIncrements;
      }
 
      public function getProductQtyIncrements()
      {
          return $this->_qtyIncrements->getProductQtyIncrements();
      }
  }```
 
and I call this method at app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml, it's work very well, but I need to do the same thing on magento_catalog/templates/product/list.phtml, but it return a error: 

```<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /home/master/autopec/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Block/Qtyincrements.php:89
Stack trace:
#0 /home/master/autopec/app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php(13): Magento\CatalogInventory\Block\Qtyincrements->getProductQtyIncrements()
#1 /home/master/autopec/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml(282): Vendor\Module\Helper\Data->getProductQtyIncrements()
#2 /home/master/autopec/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(71): include('/home/master/au...')```

Could someone help call method in this part of module please ?
````

Comment: Can you add the content of addtocart.phtml? The error is stating that the object is null so you can not call a method getId()

Comment: Ok, I put two files in driver... so you can access link and see both

addtocart.phtml (here works)
and list.phtml

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aquu47XARHZhlUrgFEKaJOTnc8cz?e=mUd3xa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use this block on product listing and it's not a good idea to use Product Page block in helper

If you want to use this logic in helper, you need to do something like:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Helper;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class Stock extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    public function getProductQtyIncrements(Product $product)
    {
        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem(
            $product->getId(),
            $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
        );

        $value = $stockItem->getQtyIncrements();
        if (!$product->isSaleable()) {
            $value = false;
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
```

And pass **product object** to `getProductQtyIncrements` method. Example

```php
$stockHelper = $this->helper('Acme\StackExchange\Helper\Stock');
// ...
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
// ...
$qtyInc = $stockHelper->getProductQtyIncrements($_product);
// ...
```

Comment: thank you so much, this really work for me :)

Comment: by the way, I still having that issue in editable cart... "edit and see cart" ... if I try call method there, like in list.phml doenst have a foreach with a collection.. it is a little diferent.. I need change too... file app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml do you have some idea how solve it?

Comment: You just need to pass product object to helper. I've provided example with collection for PLP. For cart item you have `$_item = $block->getItem(); $product = $_item->getProduct();` and the code should work properly with `$product`

Comment: I did it and this work  for me too :D, thank you a lot.

Comment: I have one more file to call php increments method...  but I dont think that it is possible
/autopec/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
dont have any php there... only knckout js(?)

Comment: I think should work the same logic like in previous answer

Comment: php doenst work at html file in magento... only in phtml file, right?

Comment: Correct. I missed file extension. For modify cart item it's need to pass your custom data into cart section (frontend) and render with JS. You need to create plugin for `\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart::getSectionData`.

Comment: How could I do that? I'm extremally new in magento development.